# posts_groupby problem

Tags: filters, groupby

On my search page I want to group the posts by post type. To do this I've got the following:

```
add_filter('posts_groupby', 'group_by_post_type' );
function group_by_post_type( $groupby ) {
  global $wpdb;
  if( is_search() ) {
     return $wpdb->posts.'.post_type';
  }

}
```

Before adding the filter I had 9 results, however after adding the filter I only have 3 results, one of each post type.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your filter will result in SQL query with `GROUP BY` statement but without [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). This will result in displaying only the first row that appear in the group that match your query and omitting the subsequent rows. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591909/group-by-behavior-when-no-aggregate-functions-are-present-in-the-select-clause) for more details.

If you want to order your results by `post_type`, you can hook to `posts_orderby` filter instead:

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'group_by_post_type', 10, 2);
function group_by_post_type($orderby, $query) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ($query->is_search) {
        return $wpdb->posts . '.post_type DESC';
    }
    // provide a default fallback return if the above condition is not true
    return $orderby;
}
```