# change posts_orderby of the callback wp_query?

Tags: wp-query, search

I found [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/177653/58895) that helps with ordering query results by the post type in my search query. But the issue is that it helps when I go to

```
https://example.com/?s=query%20string
```

that is if I search using native php search. And that's great. But I also have the search via ajax - when I type, the ajax will call my callback function that is registered on a custom rest endpoint.

So I am wondering if there is any way that I can identify that custom query so that I can reuse that filter? In the conditional:

```
if ( ! is_admin() && is_search() && is_my_custom_search_query() ) {
```

The alternative is to try to rewrite the `CASE` orderby to `WP_Query` which I am not sure is possible tbh.

Search query for ajax looks like:

```
  $query_string   = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_GET['searchString'] ) );
  $page_no        = intval( $_GET['pageNo'] );
  $posts_per_page = 9;
  $offset         = ( $page_no - 1 ) * $posts_per_page;

  $search_args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
      'post_status'    => 'publish',
      'perm'           => 'readable',
      's'              => $query_string,
      'offset'         => $offset,
  );

  $search_results = new WP_Query( $search_args );
```

Comment: What is the code for searching via AJAX?

Comment: I added it to the question. Also, I realized I can add the second parameter to the `posts_orderby` filter, which will expose the query. I will try to add a custom parameter to the `WP_Query`, and using that as an identifier.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, found the answer! I added `'query_id'`parameter in my query

```
$query_string   = sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_GET['searchString'] ) );
$page_no        = intval( $_GET['pageNo'] );
$posts_per_page = 9;
$offset         = ( $page_no - 1 ) * $posts_per_page;

$search_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'perm'           => 'readable',
    's'              => $query_string,
    'offset'         => $offset,
    'query_id'       => 'my_custom_ajax_search',
);

$search_results = new WP_Query( $search_args );
```

After that in my filter

```
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', 'my_order_search_by_posttype', 10, 2 );

function my_order_search_by_posttype( $orderby, $wp_query ) {
    if ( ! is_admin() && ( is_search() || isset( $wp_query->query['query_id'] ) && $wp_query->query['query_id'] === 'my_custom_ajax_search' ) ) {
...
    }
}
```

And it works! :)